# Moving my magento site to live server

Tags: magento-1.9, localhost

I have uploaded my Magento site from localhost to live server. I already run following steps:

1. Change database configuration such as host, username, password,
   dbname in `app/etc/local.xml`.
2. Delete/clear all cache and session in var/cache and var/session.
3. Replace local url (127.0.0.1/magento) with live site url (example: mydomain.com) in `core_config_data`

but I still found problem when I type live site URL in address bar, browser will redirect to local site URL again.

Comment: try to check your secure URL as well as normal URL in core_config_data , delete browser cache,try in private window , try to  rename htaccess and refresh,

Comment: export your core_config_data , search for old localhost URL in it , and if found re upload it , check htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Usually with this type of problem I check this list:

1. Check your live site host virtual host for redirections
2. Check your live host web server configuration for redirections
3. Check redirections rules for web server in your virtual host site folder (htaccess, etc.)
4. Check in magento admin system -> configuration -> general -> web -> secure and insecure url
5. Dump your entire live site DB in a sql file (es. myDB.sql) and grep your 127.0.0.1 -> grep '127.0.0.1' myDB.sql, if you found something replace it and reimport your DB

Then try to navigate your live site after you are sure to have completely removed all your local browser caches.